# Unable to install NetworkX on Mac to use with python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, installation, networkx

I tried to install networkx package for python 2.7 on my mac using `easy_install` and `pip`.
However, I am not able to get it work. When I used `easy_install`, I get the following message:

```
Searching for networkx
Best match: networkx 1.7
Processing networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg
networkx 1.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for networkx
Finished processing dependencies for networkx
```

Can someone provide me details of how to install them? Step by step would be great.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The message is telling you it is already installed. What is the error you get when you try to import it?

Answer (score 2):

you are installing networkx in python2.6 not in python2.7!! 
two possible solution.. .

- Download the [source](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx) and then install it as `sudo python2.7
  setup.py install`
- or use [macports](http://www.macports.org/)!! example `sudo port install
  py27-networkx @1.7`

Comment: @user198876 : don't try `sudo python2.7 network-1.7/setup.py install`!! `cd` to that `networkx1.7` dir... and then do `sudo python2.7 setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few other solutions (see @namit's correct diagnosis of your problem):

1. The first is a hack. Simply put the `networkx` package at the same level of your script and  this will be directly imported. This is the quickest solution, though not satisfactory if you are using the package in many programs.
2. Install and use `virtualenv` -- instructions on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.8.4/) and some specifics for [OS X](https://docwhat.org/virtualenv-on-os-x) -- this will allow you to use multiple versions of Python in parallel

If you are doing a lot of scientific computing on the Mac, you will encounter this sort of issue repeatedly. Consider using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh), or the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403011619/http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php).